# Qual a melhor maneira de armazenar vídeos, audios, imagens, documentos em um banco?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, aplicação-web, vídeo, armazenamento

pretendo criar um sistema de repositório em que pessoas poderão armazenar videos, audios, pdfs, imagens etc. 
Provavelmente usarei PGSQL e queia saber qual a melhor estratégia para armazenamento desses dados que podem ser diferentes em tamanho e tipo.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: creio que a melhor maneira de você fazer isso é salvando o caminho dos arquivos no banco, e salvando os arquivos em si em uma página no seu servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples é armazenar o arquivo em um diretório (pasta) e a localização (ou outra referência a este arquivo) na base de dados.
Por exemplo, digamos que você vá armazenar arquivos PDF. Você pode salvar os documentos num diretório chamado "PDFs" e criar uma tabela com id e localização destes documentos. Como em
id:0001, uri:PDFs/documento_0001.pdf

Você poderia usar um sofware como o [DSpace](http://www.dspace.org/), por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela dica do Dspace, vou estudar a melhor forma de implementar esse sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode armazenar o conteúdo de um arquivo em uma coluna do tipo [`BYTEA`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-binary.html) vejamos:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_arquivo
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, -- Identificador unico do arquivo
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,       -- Nome/Path original do arquivo
    conteudo BYTEA NOT NULL,  -- Conteudo do arquivo
    tamanho BIGINT NOT NULL,  -- Tamanho total do arquivo
    md5 TEXT NOT NULL         -- Assinatura MD5 do arquivo
);
```

O conteúdo do arquivo pode ser lido por meio da função [`pg_read_binary_file()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html) e seus atributos podem ser obtitos por meio da função [`pg_stat_file()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html).

Assumindo que o arquivo encontra-se gravado no disco do servidor de banco de dados em seu diretório [`PG_DATA`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/storage-file-layout.html):

A gravação de um arquivo arquivo nessa tabela seria algo como:

```
INSERT INTO
    tb_arquivo ( nome, conteudo, tamanho, md5 )
VALUES
    ( 'imagem.png',
    pg_read_binary_file('imagem.png'),
    (pg_stat_file('imagem.png')).size,
    md5(pg_read_binary_file('imagem.png')) );
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Armazena os arquivos no servidor e cataloga no banco de dados.
2. Para garantir a integridade dos arquivos armazenados nos directórios pode ser gerado um hash, guarda no banco, e comparar na hora da consulta.
3. Para exibir carrega os arquivos via código.